# Reduce and Solve fail to provide explicit integer solutions

Tags: equation-solving, diophantine-equations

Why is `Reduce` or `Solve` unable to provide explicit solutions over integers for such simple system of equations?

```
Reduce[{x1 x3 == 1, x2 x3 + x1 x4 == 5, 2 x2 x4 == 12}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, Integers]
```

---

[image]

Since `x3=1/x1` in all four alternatives it is evident that `x1=1` or `x1=-1` and so we have four solutions:

```
(x1==1&&x2==2&&x3==1&&x4==3)||(x1==1&&x2==3&&x3==1&&x4==2)||(x1==-1&&x2==-3&&x3==-1&&x4==-2)||(x1==-1&&x2==-2&&x3==-1&&x4==-3)
```

On the other hand `Reduce` provides explicit solutions for this similar (but more complicated) system of equations:

```
Reduce[{5 x1^2+4 x1 x3+3 x3^2==4,5 x1 x2+2 x2 x3+2 x1 x4+3 x3 x4==1,5 x2^2+4 x2 x4+3 x4^2==3},{x1,x2,x3,x4},Integers]
```

---

```
(x1==-1&&x2==0&&x3==1&&x4==1)||(x1==1&&x2==0&&x3==-1&&x4==-1)
```

Comment: This is a nonlinear Diophantine system. It's known there is no algorithm to determinate its solvability (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) for info). MMA does its best.

Comment: Just to compare. The command of Maple 2023 `isolve({x1*x3 = 1, 2*x2*x4 = 12, x1*x4 + x2*x3 = 5})` fails.

Answer (score 4):

What is even more strange that using `Reduce` twice (or `Reduce` with `Solve`) provides the explicit solutions:

```
Reduce[{x1 x3 == 1, x2 x3 + x1 x4 == 5, 2 x2 x4 == 12}, {x1, x2, x3, 
   x4}, Integers] // Reduce
Reduce[{x1 x3 == 1, x2 x3 + x1 x4 == 5, 2 x2 x4 == 12}, {x1, x2, x3, 
   x4}, Integers] // Solve
```

---

```
(x1 == -1 && x3 == -1 && x2 == -3 && 
   x4 == -2) || (x1 == -1 && x3 == -1 && x2 == -2 && 
   x4 == -3) || (x1 == 1 && x3 == 1 && x2 == 2 && 
   x4 == 3) || (x1 == 1 && x3 == 1 && x2 == 3 && x4 == 2)

{{x1 -> -1, x2 -> -3, x3 -> -1, x4 -> -2}, {x1 -> -1, 
  x2 -> -2, x3 -> -1, x4 -> -3}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 2, x3 -> 1, 
  x4 -> 3}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 1, x4 -> 2}}
```

Even `FullSimplify` fails:

```
Reduce[{x1 x3 == 1, x2 x3 + x1 x4 == 5, 2 x2 x4 == 12}, {x1, x2, x3, 
   x4}, Integers] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Also works with some alternate variable orders. For instance:

```
Reduce[{x1 x3 == 1, x2 x3 + x1 x4 == 5, 2 x2 x4 == 12},
 {x4, x1, x2, x3}, Integers]
(*
(x4 == -3 && x1 == -1 && x2 == -2 && x3 == -1) ||
 (x4 == -2 && x1 == -1 && x2 == -3 && x3 == -1) ||
 (x4 == 2 && x1 == 1 && x2 == 3 && x3 == 1) ||
 (x4 == 3 && x1 == 1 && x2 == 2 && x3 == 1)
*)
```

It maybe should be reported to WRI, since better behavior seems possible.

Comment: That's even stranger. (+1)

Comment: Actually I think the double-Reduce is stranger. Even in human, by-hand work, it can make a difference which variable you eliminate first. And it is documented that `Reduce` depends on the order of the variables, which is what made me think to try a different order. I still think `Reduce` should probably be able to do a better job here, and the double-Reduce supports that claim.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partial workaround in 13.3.1 on Windows 10:

```
FindInstance[{x1 x3 == 1, x2 x3 + x1 x4 == 5, 2 x2 x4 == 12}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, Integers, 5]
```

> FindInstance::fwsol: Warning: FindInstance found only 4 instance(s), but it was not able to prove 5 instances do not exist.
> `{{x1 -> -1, x2 -> -3, x3 -> -1, x4 -> -2}, {x1 -> -1, x2 -> -2,  x3 -> -1, x4 -> -3}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 2, x3 -> 1, x4 -> 3}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 1, x4 -> 2}}`